# How can I align the last element of a flexbox to the right with taking into account space-around?

Tags: html, flexbox

I have a flex-div with 7 elements in it.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
    <div style="width: 350px">
        [...]
    </div>
    [6 more identical divs]
</div>
```

On large screens, there are 3 `div`s in each row, on medium screens 2 and on small screens only 1. The last element is always centered but I want it to be aligned right. I tried `margin-left: auto` on the last element but due to `justify-content-around` there should be space on the right (first 2 rows on large screens, first 3 rows on medium screens). Unfortunately, `margin-left: auto` pushes the last element all the way to the right without the space from `justify-content-around`. How can I position the last element exactly as if it was an element of the right column?

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.justify-content-around {
  justify-content: space-around
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Without margin-left: auto
</h3>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    7 is centered
  </div>
</div>
<h3>
  With margin-left: auto
</h3>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="card ml-auto" style="width: 200px">
    7 is too far to the right
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the element to be in the right itself or the text inside it?

Comment: I want it on the right hand side itself. So, the `card`s of the right column should start and end at the same horizontal position.

Comment: I'm wondering whether this can't be done with calc()? It's not so easy, though, unless a little JS is allowed?

Comment: Do you want to allow for the case when there are 4 columns as well? Would the last three then also need to right-justify?

Comment: There will not be 4 columns because the width of the parent `div` is limited.

Comment: I could use `margin-left: auto; margin-right: to-be-calculated` but the value depends on whether there are 2 or 3 elements. Once I know, how many elements there are, I could more easily add hidden placeholder elements: 0 for small screens, 1 for medium screens and 2 for large screens. Not very elegant but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

It goes from

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

For 7 to come under 6 is tricky, but lets say thats not what you meant, and just want to align the 7 to left side.

Let's start removing all these style=width, If you ever want to edit the width of div you would need to edit every single div, dumping it into the CSS is much more efficient.

```
<div class="card">
 4
</div>
```

This is the adjusted CSS

```
.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.justify-content-around {
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  width: 200px;
}
```

If you want it aligned on the right then you can use JS but its difficult, since you use justify it might conflict.

Comment: You can use the `order` property on flexbox items to push item 8 to the left of item 7. But you'd still need a way to `display: none` item 8 when there are only one or two columns.

Comment: What I don't really understand is why the columns must suddenly be mixed through each other, If 7 serves as a button in the later then sure I get, but if we go from 7 to 8 to 9 to 10 etc, I can sense there's gonna be a confliction between justify-content and w/e else is being added, I'm sure its possible but I doubt using justify will be the right way to do it.

Comment: There will be no elements 8, 9, 10. There are always 7 elements. I want them to be centered horizontally in their row with `justify-content-around` except for the last row, where I want the 7th element to be adjusted right but with the space from `justify-content-around`.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works, if the element and the parent width are constant, i. e. you know, when there are 1 or 2 or 3 columns:

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.justify-content-around {
  justify-content: space-around
}

.card {
  width: 200px
}

.ml-auto {
  margin-left: auto
}

.d-none {
  display: none
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}

@media (min-width:500px) {
  .d-lg-flex {
    display: flex
  }
}

@media (min-width:700px) {
  .d-xl-flex {
    display: flex
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Centered
</h3>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card border">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    7 is centered
  </div>
</div>

<h3>
  With margin-left: auto
</h3>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card border">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="card border ml-auto">
    7 is too far to the right
  </div>
</div>

<h3>
  Correct position
</h3>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card border">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card border">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="card d-none d-lg-flex"></div>
  <div class="card d-none d-xl-flex"></div>
  <div class="card border">
    7 is now at correct position
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead of `min-width:500px` and `min-width:700px` in the media queries, use the bootstrap ones: `min-width:992px` and `min-width:1200px`. I just needed the smaller values for the snippet. Or simply use `<div class="data-box d-none d-lg-flex"></div>` and `<div class="data-box d-none d-xl-flex"></div>` for the placeholder-divs.

Answer (score 0):

While other answers here are better, **You should be tricky and smart**,

you can create another element ,say div 8,now

1. Change
   `<div class="card" style="width: 200px">8</div>` to
   `<div class="space" style="width: 200px"></div>`
2. Place this div before div 7

##### What have we done?

- We have removed all content inside that div(removed 8 from it)
- We have changed class `card` to `space`, this removes the border property we apply in css(We can even remove the class instead of changing)

```
.card {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);/*removed to our element 8*/
}
```

### Your code

- **Note:** I have added **just 1 line of code**,in **`html`**

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.justify-content-around {
  justify-content: space-around
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)
}
```

```html
<h3>
  Without margin-left: auto
</h3>
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="space" style="width: 200px"></div><!--I HAVE ADDED ONLY THIS LINE-->
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works with 2 columns but not with 3.

Comment: with 3 you need to add 2 lines of `<div class="space" style="width: 200px"></div>`,before card 7

Comment: If your columns are not fixed, then 'for my answer' to work you need `js`, is *js* ok for you?

Comment: But I do not know, if the user's screen is small, medium or large. I will provide an answer in a few minutes...

Answer (score 0):

As of your original question,
*"but due to justify-content-around"*,
You get problem when using `margin-left: auto` because of, *justify-content-* ***around***.
The solution is to use `justify-content-space-between`

### Snippet:

```css
.d-flex {
  display: flex
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.justify-content-around {
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: auto;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)
}

.card:last-child{
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-around">
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    4
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    5
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    6
  </div>
  <div class="card" style="width: 200px">
    7
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** If you need space-around also,then use margin or fixed width,or even another parent div to make it center!

Comment: Your answer works of course, but I like, that `justify-content-around` automatically adds space between and around. You're right, I could also achieve this with a parent `div` with a margin, but then it is fixed.